# Filtering on the last n weeks

Tags: sql-server, cognos

I have a report on Cognos 11 in which I want to show data from the last n (let's say 15) weeks.
I did it quick and dirty for testing purposes, using 2 filters :

```
[Année] = extract(year;getdate())
[N° Semaine] >= _week_of_year (getdate()) - 15
```

However, 2020 is coming and so if I keep those filters I will have very limited data during the first 15 weeks of the year.

What would be a good way of saying : "If we didn't reach week 15 yet, include the last week from 2019, and the week before that, etc." ?

Available to me in the framework are the following fields :

```
Date (ie : "10/12/2019")
Year (ie : 2019)
Month (ie : 12)
Week (ie : 48)
Year-Month (ie : "2019-12")
Weekday (ie : "Monday")
```

Whatever I try, I seem to run into a problem.
If I use

```
Date >= _add_months (getdate();-3)
```

for instance, the data from the first week I will get will depend on the day when I run the report.

Since the `Year-Month` data item is a string, I can't do much with it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the right way of doing it :

```
[Date] > _add_months (_add_days (getdate();-_day_of_week (getdate();1));-3)
```

It's a workaround, as I don't chose the number of weeks to go back but rather the number of months.

Comment: Your code returns a minimum date of 2019-09-16.  15 weeks ago today was 2019-09-06.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are using SQL Server, you can write code for that and Cognos will accept it.  There are some slight syntax differences to make it through the Cognos SQL parser.

```
[Date] > dateadd({week}, -15, getdate())
```

Today, this returns all dates on or after 2019-09-07 (because 2019-09-06 was 15 weeks ago).

Answer (score 0):

This answer handles the week, this is different from setting a filter >= to a date

Even if you are on different day (Mon, Tues, etc), it will go back by the number of weeks (and therefore include the whole week, you don't have to worry about data being cut off)

Try a filter like this:

```
([Year] = [Curr Year] and
[Week of the year] between [Reduce Weeks] and [Current Week])
OR
([Year] = [Prior year] and [Reduce Weeks] <= 0 and 
[Week of the year] >= 52 - [Prior year weeks])
```

Expressions:

This one expression is optional if you don't have a data item for year

- Year = Extract(year, [Date])

The rest of the data items help make the filter a little easier

- Target Date = getdate()
- Week of the year = _week_of_year ([Date])
- Curr Year = extract(year, [Target Date])
- Prior Year = extract(year, [Target Date]) -1
- Current Week = _week_of_year ([Target Date])
- Reduce Weeks = [Current Week] - 14
- Prior Year Weeks = if([Reduce Weeks] < 0)Then(abs([Reduce Weeks])+1)else(0)

To get the last n weeks, change the expression to accept a parameter

- Reduce Weeks = [Current Week] - (?NumberOfWeeks? -1)

Explanation

When the reduction in weeks goes negative is when we need to include the prior year

The OR condition in the filter handles the prior year weeks
52 weeks in a year, take the absolute value of the negative count and add 1 to offset the calculation for a prior year